error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chromedriver_autoinstaller'
I want to use chromedriver_autoinstaller and added it like below but after creating exe I faced error message error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chromedriver_autoinstaller';
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchWindowException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


def perform_working(browser="chrome", timeout_seconds=30):
    chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Chrome Driver'ı yükleyin
    driver = None

    try:
        # Tarayıcı seçeneğine göre WebDriver'ı oluştur
        if browser == "chrome":
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.headless = True
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        elif browser == "firefox":
            options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
            options.headless = True
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        elif browser == "edge":
            options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
            options.use_chromium = True
            options.headless = True
            driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported browser option.")

        if driver:
            start_button.config(text="Working")
            current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            total_links = linkler_listesi.size()
            # Çerez bildirim formunu kapatmak için gerekli adımlar


            try:
                driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('.cookie-notice-container').style.display = 'none';")
            except Exception as e:
                # Hata durumunda hata mesajını yazdırabilirsiniz
                print("Error while closing cookie notice:", e)
            for index, link in enumerate(linkler_listesi.get(0, tk.END), start=1):
                if stop_requested:
                    break
                try:
                    # Mevcut pencereyi kontrol et
                    if not is_window_alive(driver):
                        raise NoSuchWindowException("The browser window is closed.")

                    driver.get(link)
                    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout_seconds)
                    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'comment')))
                    # Aktif ziyaret edilen URL'yi maviyle işaretle
                    linkler_listesi.itemconfig(index - 1, {'bg': '#add8e6'})  # Açık mavi renk kodu
                    # nesneleri random ekle
                    url = random.choice(links_list.get(0, tk.END)) if links_list.size() > 0 else ""
                    email = random.choice(emails_list.get(0, tk.END)) if emails_list.size() > 0 else ""
                    name = random.choice(names_list.get(0, tk.END)) if names_list.size() > 0 else ""
                    message = random.choice(messages_list.get(0, tk.END)) if messages_list.size() > 0 else ""
                    comment_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'comment')
                    comment_box.send_keys(message)
                    author_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'author')
                    author_box.send_keys(name)
                    email_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
                    email_box.send_keys(email)
                    url_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'url')
                    url_box.send_keys(url)
                    submit_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'submit')
                    submit_button.click()
                    time.sleep(2)


program works well but after creating exe . I got below error message ; Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 24, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chromedriver_autoinstaller'
to compile source I used below line in pycharm 2023 ;
pyinstaller --hidden-import chromedriver_autoinstaller --onefile --clean --collect-submodules --noconsole --name myApp --icon=king.ico main.py

After that I used windows console and same error message ,
actually module is installed
C:\Users\martian\PycharmProjects\cmment\dist>pip list
Package                    Version

certifi                    2024.2.2
charset-normalizer         3.3.2
chromedriver-autoinstaller 0.6.4
distlib                    0.3.8
filelock                   3.14.0
idna                       3.7
packaging                  24.0
pip                        24.0
pipenv                     2023.12.1
platformdirs               4.2.1
python-dotenv              1.0.1
pywin32                    306
requests                   2.31.0
setuptools                 69.5.1
urllib3                    2.2.1
virtualenv                 20.26.1
webdriver-manager          4.0.1
wheel                      0.43.0
how can I fix this issue ?
thank you
I used different  compile codes :
pyinstaller --hidden-import all --onedir --clean --noconsole  --name myApp main.py

pyinstaller --hidden-import all --onedir --clean --noconsole --name myApp --icon=myIcon.ico main.py

pyinstaller --hidden-import chromedriver_autoinstaller --onefile --clean --noconsole --name myApp --icon=king.ico main.py
pyinstaller --hidden-import all --onefile --clean --noconsole --name myApp --icon=king.ico main.py

pyinstaller --hidden-import chromedriver_autoinstaller --onefile --clean --collect-submodules --noconsole --name myApp --icon=king.ico main.py


I try to add installation of the module during run time ;
try:
    import chromedriver_autoinstaller
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import subprocess
    import sys
    
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "chromedriver_autoinstaller"])
    import chromedriver_autoinstaller

but they didnt work .
